# i am trying to call back a string in PHP JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call back the value of content_columns to jquery.

PHP CODE:

```
if($act=="getcol"){
$pid=$_GET['pid'];
$domain_id = 1;
$PAGEresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE domain_id='$domain_id' AND id='$pid' ORDER BY id DESC");
$PAGErow = mysql_fetch_array($PAGEresult);
echo json_encode($PAGErow['content_columns']); 
}
```

jQuery

```
$.get("get_actions.php?act=getcol&pid="+pid, function(data){
   alert(data);
 });
```

Can someone lead me down the right path please.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: SQL Injection! be careful not to use parameters directly in your query without some sort of parameterization (to prevent against SQL injection attacks).

Comment: It keeps coming up with the same string

Comment: Is $act being defined properly to $_GET['act']?  Is it ever getting to your code? What's the string it's alerting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "same string" it is possible that it is cached.  You can disable caching with jQuery's ajax library that you are using.  You can also send a different query string such as with the system time to ensure you don't get a cached results.  You can also use POST.

You will only ever get one result from that query.  If you want multiple results, you need to iterate over mysql_fetch().  If you only want one result, add LIMIT 1 to your query.  Otherwise it is incredibly wasteful.  Finally, why use SELECT *?  Use SELECT content_columns ..